# How to get ALL orders from bigcommerce api

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, bigcommerce

I am trying to retrieve all orders from bigcommerce API from the orders V2 here: https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/e898c792ecd41-orders-v2 but I am getting `403 error`.

This is what I am doing:

```
store_hash = os.environ.get("store_harsh")
headers= {
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "X-Auth-Token": access_token,
        }
url = f"https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/{store_hash}/v2/orders"
orders = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

This is the full error:

```
{
  "status": 403,
  "title": "You don't have a required scope to access the endpoint",
  "type": "https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-docs/getting-started/api-status-codes",
  "errors": {}
}
```

I have tried specifying the scope in the headers but I still get the same error. I deeply appreciate your time

Answer (score 0):

The API is saying your API Key does not have the required permission to access orders, try re-generating a new API Key and re-submitting.

Answer (score 0):

To extend on my previous answer, here is working Python Code (which I see you are using) that I use to interface with bigcommerce.

```py
class BigCommerce:
    """
    Adaptor to communicate with bigcommerce to give us access to all functionality we require.
    """

    @newrelic.agent.background_task()
    def __init__(self, store_hash, client_id, token):
        self.store_hash = store_hash
        self.client_id = client_id
        self.token = token
        self.result = None
        self.base_url = "https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/{}/v3/".format(self.store_hash)
        self.header = {
            "X-Auth-Client": self.client_id,
            "X-Auth-Token": self.token,
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Accept": "application/json",
        }
```

Note I have the `client_id` and `token` in there. You need both items to authenticate correctly.

The fact I am using `v3` endpoint should not matter.

Also - when I call the API this is the code:

```py
request = requests.get(full_path, headers=self.header)
```

Comment: I was expecting something with the OAuth. This is already what I have so this doesn't help

Comment: Your code only has access token in it though …

Comment: I tried both. But this works for V3. I actually tried so many things to get the V2 to work before coming here for help